# spring profile / servlet context root

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I would like to set the spring profile based on the servlet context root, in servlet 2.5 environment

I tried with ApplicationContextInitializer, but was not able figure out how to access the context root from it

Is this possible, either with ApplicationContextInitializer or another method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `ConfigurableWebApplicationContext` as it follows

```
public class RuntimeEnvironmentInitializer implements ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableWebApplicationContext> {

private ConfigurableWebApplicationContext configurableApplicationContext;

@Override
    public void initialize(ConfigurableWebApplicationContext arg0) {
        this.configurableApplicationContext = arg0;
        String valueString = arg0.getServletContext().getInitParameter("InitParam");
        configurableApplicationContext.getEnvironment().setActiveProfiles("prod");
    }
}
```

Not sure if this works but have a try.

Also check the [API](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.0.8/api/org/springframework/web/context/ConfigurableWebApplicationContext.html) for that class, have a getServletConfig and getServletContext so you will be able to take some information for it, use ServletContext object if you need it.

Comment: Thanks @Koitoer, that was what I needed, I was looking for a way to call getServletContext